# Product Control Fixed Income - Interview Question

Tags: fixed-income

This was asked to me in my product control interview. What factors contribute to the daily pnl of a bond, if you exclude daily carry, price change and interest rate change? There would still be a pnl, what does it consist of?

Comment: ?? Cost of funding the position ??

Comment: What about Trading Profit or "P&L of Bonds bought/sold today".(I am thinking of the portfolio of a Bond Dealer for example).

Comment: does the bond bare credit risk? if so I'd say as time passes, you earn a bit of risk premium from there (due to survival)

Comment: If the bond is in another curremcy, then you'll hav daily P&L from the exchange rate.

Answer (score 1):

It is an interview question. As opposed to finding the one right answer, I suggest you to prove that you have an idea about fixed income.

Discuss and systematically deal with topics like

- accrued interest (clean/dirty price),
- convexity,
- curve shape (rolldown for example),
- liquidity (bid/ask spread)

and what else comes to your mind to prove that all the concepts are there. All of those can result in a change of the P&L of the bond.

Answer (score 0):

Cash flows, such as coupon payments.

Change in various curve marks, such as volatility curve if there are derivative products in the portfolio. Not too sure if there is a prepayment curve but if there is, then a change in the prepayment curve.

Changes in swap spreads.